# Align an image and making it responsive

Tags: html, css

I want an image to when I resize the page, the image goes below the text. Currently the image has `float: right` and when I resize the page, the image goes below the text but stays in the right of the page and I wanted it to go to the left of the page.

[Curently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O28dz.png)
[How it should be](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NI1NJ.png)

```css
/* TEXT */

section.QuemSou {
  float: left;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 5%;
  font-family: 'Century Gothic', sans-serif;
}

p#Quem_Sou {
  line-height: 30px;
}


/* IMAGE */

div.divimgMAIN {
  float: right;
  /* FAZER COM QUE NÃO SE USE FLOAT: RIGHT; */
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-right: 10%;
  margin-bottom: 2%;
}

img#imgMAIN {
  border-width: 2px;
  border-color: black;
  border-style: solid;
  padding: 5px 5px 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<section class="QuemSou">
  <h2>Quem Sou</h2>
  <p id="Quem_Sou">
    <b>Nome:</b> Francisco Costa<br>
    <b>Idade:</b> 19 anos<br>
    <b>Atividade:</b> Estudante<br>
    <b>Onde vivo:</b> Santa Maria da Feira
  </p>
</section>

<div class="divimgMAIN">
  <img id="imgMAIN" src="./images/linus.png">
</div>
```

If I use `float: left` it does what I need but the image is too close to the text and if I try to add any kind of padding or margin, the image goes down when it hits the margin or padding and not the text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are so many ways to solve this problem (usually call it responsive).

The most common way is to use @media in css.

-css

```
  @media only screen and (max-width: 500px) {
    div.divimgMAIN {
      float: left;
    }
```

How about this?

I hope this answer to help you.

Good luck.

Comment: This is for a "project" and im limited in the things I can use. For exemple, i can't use `display: flex;` .

Comment: I changed my answer.

Comment: Thank you :D
Do you know other ways? Just for reference.